# JS remove class from div, when text field in empty?

Tags: javascript

I have a search bar where the results are displayed centered of the page with a fixed div. And an absolute div covers the page behind the results with a semi transparent black. How could I remove the class ".coverOn" added on the keyup function, If I just deleted what I put into the search field without refreshing the page?

Thanks.

```
<styles>
.coverOn {
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
    z-index:8;
}
#output { /* holds search results */
    position:fixed;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    top:130px;
    width:400px;
    margin:0 auto;
    -webkit-border-radius:15px;
    -moz-border-radius:15px;
    border-radius:15px;
    z-index:12;
    }
</styles>

<body>
 <div id="cover"></div>
 <div id="Search">
     <input type="text" name="search" onkeyup="searchq();" value="" required class="SearchField" />
    <div id="output"></div>
  </div>
</body>

<script>
function searchq() {
    var searchTxt = $("input[name='search']").val();
    $.post("../php/productSearch.php", {searchVal: searchTxt}, function(output) {
     $("#output").html(output);
     document.getElementById("cover").className = "coverOn";
  }); 
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove class if `searchTxt` string is empty:

```
function searchq() {
    var searchTxt = $("input[name='search']").val().trim();
    $.post("../php/productSearch.php", {searchVal: searchTxt}, function (output) {
        $("#output").html(output);
        document.getElementById("cover").className = searchTxt ? "coverOn" : "";
    });
}
```

or since you are using jQuery it can be simpler:

```
$("#cover").toggleClass("coverOn", searchTxt);
```

Answer (score 1):

use removeClass('selector');

```js
$('input').on('keyup', function() {
  $('.red').removeClass('red');
})
```

```css
.red {
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" />
<div class="red">red</div>
```

Comment: and I think use blur instead of keyup is better.

Answer (score 0):

What you could do, rather than operating with classes, is instead of

```
.coverOn {
position:absolute;
width:100%;
height:100%;
background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
z-index:8;
}
```

do

```
#output:not(:empty) {
position:absolute;
width:100%;
height:100%;
background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
z-index:8;
}
```

So long as when you do an empty search, it returns an empty result.

Your resulting javascript would be

```
function searchq() {
    var searchTxt = $("input[name='search']").val();
    $.post("../php/productSearch.php", {searchVal: searchTxt}, function(output) {
     $("#output").html(output);
  });
```